# how to get the character preceding a gap and after a gap in python

Tags: python

Please I have several alignment files. I used regular expression to pull out those with gaps using if re.search(r"A-Z[A-Z]", seq):to get sequences with gaps e.g M--------A . My question is IN PYTHON how do I get the character M and A which are preceding and after the gap? 
This is an example of the file I am working with below. Thank you.

> 3ENMA 113E84F72145D181 316 XRAY  2.350  0.215  0.269 no Dual specificity mitogen-activated protein kinase kinase 6  [Homo sapiens] ||3ENMB 3ENMC 3ENMD
>   HHHHDYDIPTTENLYFQGAME----------------NFEVKADDLEPIMELGRGAYGVVEKMRHVPSGQIMA
>   VKRIRATVNSQEQKRLLMDLDISMRTVDCPFTVTFYGALFREGDVWICMELMDTSLGIVKALEHLHSKLSVIHRDVKPSNVLINALGQVKMCDFGISGYLVDDVAKDIDAGCKPYMAPERINPELNQKGYSVKSDIWSLGITMIELAILRFPYDSWGTPFQQLKQVVEEPSPQLPADKFSAEFVDFTSQCLKKNSKERPTYPELMQHPFFT----------

Comment: Please format your code as code. Please give examples of what the input is, and what constitutes a "gap". Apart from that, practise Regular Expressions, e.g. here: https://regex101.com/ Especially look into grouping in regexes - and probably non-capturing expressions (those using the notation (?:...))

Comment: This is an example of my input file  >3ENMA 113E84F72145D181 316 XRAY  2.350  0.215  0.269 no Dual specificity mitogen-activated protein kinase kinase 6 <MP2K6_HUMAN(45-332)> [Homo sapiens] ||3ENMB 3ENMC 3ENMD
MSYYHHHHHHDYDIPTTENLYFQGAME-----------------NFEVKADDLEPIMELGRGAYGVVEKMRHVPSGQIMA
VKRIRATVNSQEQKRLLMDLDISMRTVDCPFTVTFYGALFREGDVWICMELMDTSLDKFYKQVIDKGQTIPEDILGKIAV
SIVKALEHLHSKLSVIHRDVKPSNVLINALGQVKMCDFGISGYLVDDVAKDIDAGCKPYMAPERINPELNQKGYSVKSDI
WSLGITMIELAILRFPYDSWGTPFQQLKQVVEEPSPQLPADKFSAEFVDFTSQCLKKNSKERPTYPELMQHPFFTLHESK
GTDVASFVKLILA-------

Comment: Give your example in your post above. You can edit your post by adding your example.

Comment: Get the beginning and end indices of the match objects then use those to get the characters you want - https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.span

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial service. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links on that page.  You should invest some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples. It will give you an introduction to the tools Python has to offer and you may even start to get ideas for solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You want to capture the uppercase letter `[A-Z]` immediately before and after a 'gap' consisting of a number of dashes `-+`.

So your regular expression should contain `([A-Z])-+([A-Z])`

To extract the two uppercase characters, you could use `re.replace` with `$1` and `$2` as part of the replacement string.